# Changing toggle-button style

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, html5-canvas

I want to change the style of the toggle-button  like this.

[image: Toggle-Button]

This is my sample code:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input id="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d_Sections_0__Fields_6__Id" name="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d.Sections[0].Fields[6].Id" type="hidden" value="{D7AB5D2E-444F-49C7-91E4-564496D7C8A2}">
  <div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Value field is required." id="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d_Sections_0__Fields_6__Value" name="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d.Sections[0].Fields[6].Value" type="checkbox" value="true" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;">
    <span class="button-checkbox bootstrap-checkbox">
      <button type="button" class="btn clearfix custom-btn">
        <span class="icon fa fa-check theme-text" style="display:none;"></span>
        <span class="icon fa fa-check-square"></span>
        <span class="icon cb-icon-check-indeterminate" style="display:none;"></span>
      </button>
    </span>
    <label class="switch">
      <input name="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d.Sections[0].Fields[6].Value" type="checkbox" value="false">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d.Sections[0].Fields[6].Value" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ako5z18m/1)

I tried few CSS but it is not exactly what I want. I tried:

```
  .switchbtn:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 32px;
    width: 26px;            
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

Comment: Anybody else click the toggles?  LOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo CSS selectors to modify the look and feel of the toggle button. Since `:before` is already used to create the circular toggle, I have used `:after` to add the text. Obviously, there are more ways to do this, and the below is a just a quick way to show you how to achieve this.

Note that you will have to modify the pseudo selectors for both the states (normal and `checked`) as you want different colors.

Check the code snippet below and use that as a starting point to modify/tweak styles as per your need.

Hope this helps.

```css
  .switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
  }

  .switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  .switchbtn {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid #bbb;

    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }

 .switchbtn:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  
  }
  
 .switchbtn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "OFF";
    right: 3px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }

  input:checked+.switchbtn {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #2196F3;
  }

  input:focus+.switchbtn {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }

  input:checked+.switchbtn:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:checked+.switchbtn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "ON";
    left: 7px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }

  /* Rounded sliders */

  .switchbtn {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }

  .switchbtn:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .switch button {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input class="switchbtn" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Value field is required." id="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d_Sections_0__Fields_6__Value" name="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d.Sections[0].Fields[6].Value" type="checkbox" value="true" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d\.Sections\[0\]\.Fields\[6\]\.Value-error wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d\.Sections\[0\]\.Fields\[6\]\.Value-error">
    <span class="button-checkbox bootstrap-checkbox switchbtn">
    <button type="button" class="btn clearfix custom-btn">
    <span class="icon fa fa-check theme-text" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span class="icon fa fa-check-square" style="display: inline;"></span>
    <span class="icon cb-icon-check-indeterminate" style="display:none;"></span>
    </button></span><input name="wffm302ebacf2b634d59b0dc1e81e451bc8d.Sections[0].Fields[6].Value" type="hidden" value="false">
</label>
```

Hope this helps.